# Calculating Next Due Date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, getdate

I'm new to T-SQL and have come upon a piece of code and was wondering if someone could help me understand what is happening. The point of the code is to calculate the date the next payment.

```
CASE 
WHEN MONTH(table.field-10) < MONTH(GETDATE())
     THEN CONVERT(DATE,((MONTH(GETDATE()) - MONTH(table.field-10)) *30)  + (table.field))
WHEN MONTH(table.field-10) = MONTH(GETDATE())
     THEN CONVERT(DATE,FA_NEXTDUE)
WHEN MONTH(table.field-10) > MONTH(GETDATE()) 
     THEN CONVERT(DATE,(table.field) - ((MONTH(table.field-10) - MONTH(GETDATE())) *30))
END AS CurrentDueDate
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I suspected that was the answer but thought there had to be implicit conversion to days somewhere  and I was missing it.  Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 1):

This appears quite poorly written as it uses a "month" function that does not take the year into account.  It appears to trying to determine if ten days before the date in "field" is in the same month as the current date.  However, due to this not taking the year into account the output is a bit erratic.

A better way would be to use the datediff function.

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(month, getdate(), (dateadd(day, -10, table.field))) < 0 then dateadd(month, DATEDIFF(month, getdate(), (dateadd(day, -10, table.field))), table.field)
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(month, getdate(), (dateadd(day, -10, table.field))) = 0 then CONVERT(Date, fa_nextdue)
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(month, getdate(), (dateadd(day, -10, table.field))) > 0 then dateadd(month, DATEDIFF(month, getdate(), (dateadd(day, -10, table.field))), table.field)
```

Even with this correction, I am skeptical that the output is what the business would require.  You might want to dig into the requirements a little to see what exactly should be returned here.

*FYI table.field-10 = ten days before the "field" date.*

Comment: I'd be very careful with this `column-10` shorthand. If the underlying data type changes to `DATE` or `DATETIME2`, this code will break. `DATEADD` is more cumbersome to type, but much more reliable and consistent.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the sample code to use dateadd rather than the subtraction.